# Why did my WiFi, bluetooth and hotspot stop working all of a sudden?

Tags: bluetooth, wifi-hotspot, wifi-tethering, bluetooth-tethering

I had this very awkward experience, today. My Samsung Galaxy A10s running Android 10 has ran into some serious trouble. I am shocked to find that my Wi-Fi is not turning on, my bluetooth is frozen and my hotspot is also not turning on. I do not realize, why this is happening. I am not a regular Wi-Fi user, I prefer Mobile networks, and it is extremely shocking to find that my device is not properly working.

**My attempts to fix this**

- I tried clearing the cache memory, of all apps, individually one by one, freeing up almost 120+ MB from internal memory.
- I tried booting into **safe mode**, and then tried to enable Wi-Fi / hotspot/bluetooth, but *still* my efforts were all in vain.
- I updated it manually to get the latest patches. But, still it is **not** fixed.
- I tried *resetting* the network settings to default, but, still, my problems still persist.

I do not know what else to do, to save my phone. All these features, that I lost are very very important to me. I humbly request to help me. Every help will greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did the device install any updates recently (check security update date)? If not the only option is to save all your files and perform a factory reset. If after the FR Wifi/Bluetooth still do not work it will be most likely a hardware problem (Bluetooth and Wifi is usually provided by the same chip).

Comment: @Robert Thankyou, for the reply. **After** I got this problem, I updated my phone, thinking that the update would fix it. But it didn't do anything. Also, I'm not in a position to do factory reset! How can the chip get damaged?

Comment: Chips are aging just like humans. Additionally circuits can break and cables as used for antennas can break, too.

Comment: @Robert This phone, in question is only one and a half year old. And the WiFi and Bluetooth capabilities are turned on / used only when needed. Everything was working quickly and fast, just the day before all these problems surfaced.

Answer (score 0):

It's common for Wi-Fi, Bluetooth and Hotspot to break together in Samsung devices since the OEM uses low-end hardware implementation for that part in budget devices. I myself have 2 Samsung devices (one budget, one midranger) and a Samsung T561 with the same issue.

**So yes, its a hardware issue**